# SSRS Page Footer Containing Name of Row Group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

[Report Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpOFq.png)

See the report example image. I'm trying to add the name of the row group (highlighted row in tablix on image) to the page footer so that it'll print at the bottom of each page. I have page breaks set for that row group, so I'd like it to use the current row group name for each page. Is this possible to do?

I know I can use the parameter in the page footer, but the parameter for that row group allows multiple values as we print one report for all timekeepers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an actual page footer (and not row group 'footer') then as long as you have the text that you need displayed in the tablix already then you can use the ReportItems collection to get to the value.

If you don't have the value already showing in the tablix, add it (you can always change it to white text if you don'twant to see it).

Let's assume that in your image , the `<<Expr>>` in the first column highlighted in yellow is what you want to see in the footer. Click this textbox and find it's name (e.g. `Textbox123`).

Now in your footer you should be able to to use `=FIRST(ReportItems!Textbox123.Value)` making sure it's spelled correctly, it's case sensitive.